# References in Excel 2013 VBA editor is grayed out

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I need help with a tool I have created for my office team to monitor their effort utilization using Excel 2013 VBA Macro.
Unfortunately, the Macro could not find Add-Ins in anyone else's system than mine.
In other's system, the "References" button in VBA editor is grayed out.
In order to make that work, they first need to restart the Editor and then try the Macro.
However, I am looking for the Macro to work seemlessly without having users to go to VBA editor.
Please help me with the solution.

Comment: Please post the code of your macro.

Answer (score 25):

One more caveat to it. You must make sure you press the stop button before you go to tools and references.

If the macro keeps running or if the error is highlighted, the references part will still be grayed out and none of the measures described above would work.

Answer (score 3):

After a long research, I found some basic solutions that works fine on systems.
If the VBA editor is showing the grayed "References" or "Additional Controls" buttons then there are two possible reason.

1st of them is answered in below link - 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/856804/vba-editor-references-option-is-grayed-out

2nd reason is related to the "Administrative Access".
To solve the issue, try to run "Excel" as administrator once, then select the respective "Active X Controls" and "References" that are required to run the Macro.

Once this is done, then the user will never face the problem again.

Comment: I use VBA in CATIA , the same happened to me, and none of the above was the solution

Comment: Try to close all Excel files and then open Excel as administrator from Start Menu. Hopefully this will work.

Comment: One addition here that caught me was I was in debug mode which disables access to References.