New Word documents start macro-enabled but are then disabled and it seems nothing can re-enable them
Since the latest Word for Windows update I have been unable to create new Word documents that remain macro-enabled. When I first create a new .docm I can apply 1 (one) macro from my attached Normal template; if I try another, I get an error message that says "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications / System Error &H80070057 (-2147024809)."
I have been unable to find any way to get around this. I have been using .docm's, not ordinary .docx's; I have looked extensively online and have tried the oft-repeated settings in the Trust Center (Enable all Macros, Trust access to the VBA project object model, choose a trusted location (I have added my own locations as well as using the Word Start-up folder). I may get the macros to work for a while, but sooner or later I get the dreaded error message again, and my .docm is back to having its macros disabled.
I find it strange that I do not experience any problems like this with Word for Mac. If I open a document that already contains macros it simply asks permission to enable them, and then everything works fine. If I create a new doc and add macros, they simply work.
The one idea I have not followed up with WinWord is to create a new Normal.docm. My macros and other items (AutoCorrects etc.) in my Normal.docm have been built up over many years and it would be a huge investment of time and effort to try and reconstruct them. Can anyone reading this suggest a less drastic solution?
Many thanks for any help you can give.

"it would be a huge investment of time and effort to try and reconstruct them" - why not just export the modules then import them into a new Normal.docm?

Sounds wonderful, @CHill60! How would I do that?

Open the VB Editor. In the Project Explorer window right click on each module that you want to export and select "Export file", or press Ctrl+E. When you want to import the files into the new template right click the project name and select "Import File", or press Ctrl+M

Have you seen this one @Steve? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71939033/getting-system-error-h80070057-2147024809

Many thanks, @Timothy Rylatt. I'm out of time to work on this right now, but will respond as soon as I can get to it. I assume to create a new Normal.dotm I simply rename or delete the old one and Word will automatically create a replacement?

Thanks for those further suggestions, @hennep.

To answer the sub-question - how to export/import all of the files - it sounds like there is a lot, so an automated way of doing it is in the functions below.
A few comments

this was adapted for Excel VBA originally so some of the naming conventions might appear strange! I have run it in Word though.
I can't remember where I found the original so have not been able to credit them here. This was not my original work! If any reader knows please comment and I will add credit where credit is due.

Option Explicit
' Tools, References, Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility
'File, Options, Trust Center, Trust Center Settings, Macro Settings, "Trust access to the VBA Project object model
Public Sub ExportModules()
    Dim bExport As Boolean
    Dim wkbSource As Word.Document
    Dim szSourceWorkbook As String
    Dim szExportPath As String
    Dim szFileName As String
    Dim cmpComponent As VBIDE.VBComponent

    ''' The code modules will be exported in a folder named.
    ''' VBAProjectFiles in the Documents folder.
    ''' The code below create this folder if it not exist
    ''' or delete all files in the folder if it exist.
    If FolderWithVBAProjectFiles = "Error" Then
        MsgBox "Export Folder does not exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    On Error Resume Next
        Kill FolderWithVBAProjectFiles & "\*.*"
    On Error GoTo 0

    ''' NOTE: This workbook must be open in Word.
    szSourceWorkbook = ActiveDocument.Name
    Set wkbSource = Application.Documents(szSourceWorkbook)
    
    If wkbSource.VBProject.Protection = 1 Then
    MsgBox "The VBA in this workbook is protected," & _
        "not possible to export the code"
    Exit Sub
    End If
    
    szExportPath = FolderWithVBAProjectFiles & "\"
    
    For Each cmpComponent In wkbSource.VBProject.VBComponents
        
        bExport = True
        szFileName = cmpComponent.Name

        ''' Concatenate the correct filename for export.
        Select Case cmpComponent.Type
            Case vbext_ct_ClassModule
                szFileName = szFileName & ".cls"
            Case vbext_ct_MSForm
                szFileName = szFileName & ".frm"
            Case vbext_ct_StdModule
                szFileName = szFileName & ".bas"
            Case vbext_ct_Document
                ''' This is a worksheet or workbook object.
                ''' Don't try to export.
                bExport = False
        End Select
        
        If bExport Then
            ''' Export the component to a text file.
            cmpComponent.Export szExportPath & szFileName
            
        ''' remove it from the project if you want
        '''wkbSource.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove cmpComponent
        
        End If
   
    Next cmpComponent

    MsgBox "Export is ready"
End Sub
Public Sub ImportModules()

    Dim wkbTarget As Word.Document
    Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim objFile As Scripting.File
    Dim szTargetWorkbook As String
    Dim szImportPath As String
    Dim szFileName As String
    Dim cmpComponents As VBIDE.VBComponents


    'Get the path to the folder with modules
    If FolderWithVBAProjectFiles = "Error" Then
        MsgBox "Import Folder not exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ''' NOTE: This workbook must be open in Excel.
    szTargetWorkbook = ActiveDocument.Name
    Set wkbTarget = Application.Documents(szTargetWorkbook)
    
    If wkbTarget.VBProject.Protection = 1 Then
    MsgBox "The VBA in this workbook is protected," & _
        "not possible to Import the code"
    Exit Sub
    End If

    ''' NOTE: Path where the code modules are located.
    szImportPath = FolderWithVBAProjectFiles & "\"
        
    Set objFSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    If objFSO.GetFolder(szImportPath).Files.Count = 0 Then
       MsgBox "There are no files to import"
       Exit Sub
    End If


    Set cmpComponents = wkbTarget.VBProject.VBComponents
    
    ''' Import all the code modules in the specified path
    ''' to the ActiveWorkbook.
    For Each objFile In objFSO.GetFolder(szImportPath).Files
    
        If (objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name) = "cls") Or _
            (objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name) = "frm") Or _
            (objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name) = "bas") Then
            cmpComponents.Import objFile.Path
        End If
        
    Next objFile
    
    MsgBox "Import is ready"
End Sub

Function FolderWithVBAProjectFiles() As String
    Dim WshShell As Object
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim SpecialPath As String

    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    SpecialPath = WshShell.SpecialFolders("MyDocuments")

    If Right(SpecialPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        SpecialPath = SpecialPath & "\"
    End If
    
    If FSO.FolderExists(SpecialPath & "VBAProjectFiles") = False Then
        On Error Resume Next
        MkDir SpecialPath & "VBAProjectFiles"
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
    
    If FSO.FolderExists(SpecialPath & "VBAProjectFiles") = True Then
        FolderWithVBAProjectFiles = SpecialPath & "VBAProjectFiles"
    Else
        FolderWithVBAProjectFiles = "Error"
    End If
    
End Function

EDIT:
Response to comment - how to use the code above
Use Alt-F11 (or Developer, Visual Basic on the ribbon) to open the VBA IDE
On the left hand side in Project, right click on the document / template and select Insert, Module
(If the project pane is not visible Ctr-R or View, Project Explorer)
Paste all the code above into the window.
Position cursor somewhere "inside" ExportModules and hit F5,
or position cursor at top of module, hit F5 or click the run > icon, and select ExportModules from the list.
Repeat for the target document/template but run ImportModules

Sorry about the formatting - it's not playing nice today

Many thanks for this—looks like it could save a lot of work. Forgive me for having to ask—I'm not a programmer or developer, just an ordinary Word user…—but how would I actually apply this? It looks like a VBA script: Do I just open the VBA editor in Word, paste it in, and apply it like a macro?

Yes you are right. Alt-F11 will open the Word VBA IDE . ah - I'm going to run out of characters. I will Edit my solution. Thanks @johnM for sorting out my formatting!

Thanks for explaining that! I'm setting aside time to try this tomorrow. I'll let you know how it goes.

I tried your script today; but sorry to say, it hit an error and couldn’t continue. I have a screenshot, but don't know how to attach it here. The error message said "Compile error: User-defined type not defined", and part of the 10th line of the script was highlighted: "cmpComponent As VBIDE.VBComponent". Does that tell you enough to know what was happening?

See the comment at the top of the code - it requires a Reference to be added  via Tools, References: Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility

CHill60, I'm really sorry to come back to you again. I've added the Reference and successfully exported the modules; but when I try to import them into a different document, I get the same problem again (missing Reference), but when I ty to (re-)add it, "References" is grayed out on the Tools menu. Would you be willing to have one more attempt with me before I resort to recreating my macros etc. in a new Normal.dotm?

I've never come across that myself but things I would try ...
Try adding a blank module into the (new) Word project.
Try saving the document first then re-opening it
Check the Trust Center settings still allow macros

Ah - I also found this ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47157643/references-in-excel-2013-vba-editor-is-grayed-out

Many thanks for those suggestions, CHill60. I've been overtaken by other things today, but will try them asap.
